# How to initialize Microsoft Monaco editor in a browser using simple JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, monaco-editor

I am trying to initialize a text/code editor using [Microsoft Monaco](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/). I would like to use **core JavaScript** or even jQuery but **no NodeJS dependency**. Is that possible?

Some relevant examples:

[Get the value of Monaco Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086013/get-the-value-of-monaco-editor)

[Example in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/developit/bwgkr6uq/)

I have the following code, which is not working:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="width:800px;height:600px;border:1px solid grey"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>


<script>
require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'monaco-editor/min/vs' }});
require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {
    window.editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'),                 {
        value: [
            'function x() {',
            '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");',
            '}'
        ].join('\n'),
        language: 'javascript'
    });
});

function save() {
   // get the value of the data
   var value = window.editor.getValue()
   saveValueSomewhere(value);     
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've added a working example below. Regarding your other question:

> I would like to use core JavaScript or even jQuery but no NodeJS dependency. Is that possible?

[monaco-editor](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/) **IS** written in JavaScript (TypeScript compiled to JavaScript) and does not use jQuery.  Node is not really relevant in the context you've described.

Please let me know if this helps.

```js
require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@latest/min/vs' }});
window.MonacoEnvironment = { getWorkerUrl: () => proxy };

let proxy = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`
 self.MonacoEnvironment = {
  baseUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@latest/min/'
 };
 importScripts('https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@latest/min/vs/base/worker/workerMain.js');
`], { type: 'text/javascript' }));

require(["vs/editor/editor.main"], function () {
 let editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
  value: [
   'function x() {',
   '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");',
   '}'
  ].join('\n'),
  language: 'javascript',
  theme: 'vs-dark'
 });
});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@latest/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. I wanted to be able to load Monaco on demand and now I can.

Comment: Works great. Thank you!

Comment: Any way of doing this without using require.js?

Comment: @Alvaro check out the examples repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor-samples/

Comment: @Alvaro this isn't using RequireJS. Microsoft created it's own `require` object that it uses to configure Monaco, but it's not RequireJS (although it shares the same object name).

Comment: @Peter Is there a way to bundle this with webpack? This results in a 'Module not found' error for me.

Comment: @InbarAzulay sure, but you must follow the stated rules of this website and create a NEW, well-formed question.

Comment: @Peter of course. I've done this at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67059283/error-cant-resolve-vs-editor-editor-main-in-when-lazy-loading-monaco-e but didn't get any responses yet

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/eajgr2y9/ for a jsfiddle working example

Answer (score 1):

You can also add editor as simple js code without requirejs.

1. Download repo from [monaco-editor](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor)
2. Build monaco-editor for browser

> cd monaco-editor && npm run build-website

3. You can copy module from website/node_modules/monaco-editor folder created after build,

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>   <head>
>       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
>       <link
>           rel="stylesheet"
>           data-name="vs/editor/editor.main"
>           href="../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.css"
>       />
>   </head>
>   <body>
>       <h2>Monaco Editor Sync Loading Sample</h2>
>       <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid grey"></div>
>
>       <script>
>           var require = { paths: { vs: '../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs' } };
>       </script>
>       <script src="../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
>       <script src="../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.nls.js"></script>
>       <script src="../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js"></script>
>
>       <script>
>           var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
>               value: ['function x() {', '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");', '}'].join('\n'),
>               language: 'javascript'
>           });
>       </script>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```