# Error: Can't resolve 'vs/editor/editor.main' in "..." when using monaco-editor-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack, monaco-editor

When Lazy loading and bundling using `monaco-editor-webpack-plugin`, Monaco editor returns the following error:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vs/editor/editor.main' in '...'`

`resolve 'vs/editor/editor.main' in '...'`

It seems like the has no idea about the require.config function that sets the config path. All the worker files are created.

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require("monaco-editor-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "./bundle.js",
  },
  mode: "development",
  plugins: [
    new MonacoWebpackPlugin()
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js"],
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/"),
    },
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      }, {
        test: /\.ttf$/,
        use: ['file-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

This is the way I require the Monaco editor:

```
require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.8.3/min/vs' } });
window.MonacoEnvironment = { getWorkerUrl: () => proxy };

let proxy = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`
        self.MonacoEnvironment = {
            baseUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.8.3/min/'
        };
        importScripts('https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.8.3/min/vs/base/worker/workerMain.js');
    `], { type: 'text/javascript' }));

require(["vs/editor/editor.main"], function () {
    let editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
        value: [
            'function x() {',
            '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");',
            '}'
        ].join('\n'),
        language: 'javascript',
        theme: 'vs-dark'
    });
});
```

Is there anybody that came accross this same issue and found a solution for this error?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a configuration problem relating to the [monaco-editor-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin#options).

To fix this, try updating your `webpack.config.js` file, specifically, under the `plugins` key, you can provide an configuration object when constructing the plugin:

```js
const path = require("path");
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require("monaco-editor-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "./bundle.js",
  },
  mode: "development",
  plugins: [
    new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
        publicPath: "/dist/"                        // Add the public path to monaco
      })
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js"],
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/"),
    },
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      }, {
        test: /\.ttf$/,
        use: ['file-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```