# How can I access code from the monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor

I can't find a getter method in the API docs for monaco editor, is there an example for how to get code that a user has entered in the editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the code that an user has entered by calling the following method:

```js
// Store your editor in a variable
var codeEditor = monaco.editor.create(...);

// Then, whenever you want to retrieve the code, use this.
var codeFromUser = codeEditor.getValue();
```

You can find similar answers here: [Get the value of Monaco Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086013/get-the-value-of-monaco-editor)

Comment: thank you, I was going crazy trying to figure it out.

Comment: No problem @DionCoder, I'm glad to help. Also, as I see that you're into Monaco, you may also want to checkout other libraries like [Highlight](https://highlightjs.org) and [Prism](https://prismjs.com), it may come in handy too!